# How to get the position of a span nested within a textarea

Tags: jquery

I have a span that is nested within a textarea, and would like to get the offset of this span relative to the document.  Zero is always returned for left and top, and I'm not sure why.

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c2J36/) with the following code to demo

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#textarea1").html("1234 <span id='span1' style='color:red'>5678</span>");
  var offset = $("#span1").offset();
  alert("span1 left: " + offset.left + "  top: " + offset.top);
});
```

I see why the position of the span would be zero, relative to the textarea.  But I don't understand why the offset is returning zero.  If anyone could help me out here I'd appreciate it.

---

Edit: My goal was to position something above the span when it was clicked.  I couldn't get the offset of the span mentioned above, so I decided to use the mouse coordinates instead.

```
$("#id").dblclick(function(e){
 alert("X: " + e.pageX + " Y: " + e.pageY);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DOM is unaware of this `span` because it is simply contained in the `value` property of the textarea.

In order to calculate the x,y coordinates on the page you would need to follow the characters/lines in the text area and calculate an approximate location to place the cursor. This is not a simple task primarily because calculating line-breaks on free flowing text (especially without a mono-space font is challenging).

Comment: I figured it was something like that.  I went ahead and implemented what I wanted to do in a different way, thanks.